# Can't type 0 with XQuartz?

Tags: xquartz

I installed Inkscape using `brew cask install inkscape` on OS X 10.11.6, and the XQuartz that came with it has a major problem: I can't type the number 0! The key is simply nonfunctional (you similarly can't type a closing parenthesis). I can't find any other questions that mention the number 0 being impossible to type. I've never changed any settings related to XQuartz.

Comment: Does Homebrew have a facility to file a bug report?

Comment: I assume you can type 0 and close parenthesis outside of inkscape. Looks like a wonky key-mapping problem. Have you tried re-installing?

Comment: Yes. I reinstalled using `brew cask remove xquartz` and `brew cask install xquartz`. The bug was present in the newly installed version. Note that the first 0 you type after you XQuartz starts works. Later zeroes do not work.

Comment: For no apparent reason, zeroes and close parentheses started. I had been using a trick using bettertouchtool to work around the bug, but I disabled it, and the bug mysteriously disappeared as mysteriously as it had come in the first place. I don't know what changed. It did not work at first when I reinstalled it.

Comment: Oh, I think I might know where the problem came from, though I don't know why this would cause that problem. I had a .Xmodmap in my home folder which I didn't know about that came from my Linux installation and that got copied in with a bunch of other stuff because I pasted a backup of a bunch of bash scripts etc into my OS X home folder and included that for some reason. If it was loading that .Xmodmap and the keycodes are different between OS X and Linux, that might explain it. I recently changed the .Xmodmap because I wanted to make Command act as Control, so I overwrote the Linux one.